# Test URL doesn't work in chrome but works in Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome

I try to create spring boot web project.

```
http://localhost:9082/beautysalon/
```

When I run this URL in Chrome browser then download some file. But when run it in Internet Explorer Project work successfully. Why coming this issue.

This is project structure.

Include the css and js file inside the static folder.
And .jsp file added to webapp/view folder

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information. How exactly did you create the project?

Comment: Hi tbrk, I updated Question

Comment: It may have something to do with the header (e.g., content type) being sent by the webserver. Have you tried using the chrome developer tools to get information on the headers, e.g., [this blog post](https://blog.versionone.com/spy-on-browser-http-requests/) (untested).